# Am I allowed to say thanks?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes a person's answer is really helpful, but I'm not sure if thanking the person as a comment is appropriate (as it's not a discussion forum).

Comment: [Related.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/?cb=1#comment-68560)

Answer (score 20):

### Vote for them!

That's the proper way of saying thanks.

You're spot-on though, we do like to keep the chatter down to a minimum as it makes it harder for people to find good answers if they have to wade through comments.

But it's unlikely anybody (users or moderators) would mind the *occasional* comment letting people know how good an answer is. As somebody who has written one or two answers and has had a few thankful comments in return, I can say it is nice to have personal feedback.

I think you should go for it, but save thanks-comments for the truly exceptional answers.

Comment: Thank you for answering this! I voted.

Comment: +1 That's a very good comment @MarcoCeppi - I really appreciate the feedback!